Cookie not sent when I deploy my app on vercel
I coded a simple authentication program using cookies and expressjs, My code runs fine when in the localhost environment, but when deployed to Vercel my program code doesn't run well (cookies are not sent and are not set on the client browser)
Here is my express code

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');



const app = express();



app.use(cors(

  {

    origin: 'https://tester-virid-seven.vercel.app/',

    credentials: true

  }

));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.set("trust proxy", 1);



app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  res.status(200).cookie("AUTH", "example", {

    maxAge: 900000,

    httpOnly: false,

    secure: true,

    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000*60)

  }).json({cookie: req.cookies.AUTH});

});



app.listen(3000, () => {

  console.info('app is running...');

});

And this is the client/frontend program codeAnd this is the client/frontend program code


<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <title>Document</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script>

      axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

      axios.get('https://cookie-test-theta.vercel.app/')

      .then(res => console.info(res))

      .catch(err => console.error(err));

      alert(document.cookie);

    </script>

  </body>

</html>

I want the program code to work well when deployed (cookies are sent and set)I want the program code to work well when deployed (cookies are sent and set)

From the looks of your express code and CORS configuration, your frontend is running on https://tester-virid-seven.vercel.app and you're allowing requests from that host to the express app running on another host.
You would need sameSite: 'None' in your cookie options to allow sending of cookies between two different hosts. See https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie
Alternatively you could run both the frontend and backend on Vercel in one app, on the same host.
